# How do I fix positional argument self error

Tags: python

I'm getting an error when I try to run my code that's saying I'm missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

```
import urllib.request
import re
from lxml import html

class test:           
    def start(self) :

        url = 'http://money.cnn.com/data/dow30/'

        global Ticker

        increase = 0
        while increase < 30:

            req = urllib.request.Request(url)
            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            respData = resp.read()

            html_data = html.fromstring(respData)

            Ticker = html_data.xpath('//a[@class="wsod_symbol"]/text()')[increase]

            print(Ticker)

            return Ticker              
            increase += 1
    start()

    def earnings(self):

        url = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE:' + Ticker

        req = urllib.request.Request(url)
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        respData = resp.read()

        html_data = html.fromstring(respData)

        eps = html_data.xpath('//td[@class="val"]/text()')[7]

        blah = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', eps)

        print(float(blah[0]))
```

Comment: please correct intendation

Comment: Your code seems to have several problems like reurning in while and uodating variable inside that,calling member function wiithout instance

Comment: And calling `start` from top-level in the class. Pretty sure that's illegal.

Comment: Ok that's cool but how do I fix the positional argument.

Comment: @JEs You didn't say where the error is, or what function causes it.

Comment: Line 28 in start()

Comment: @JEs You're not calling `start` on an instance, and the place you're calling it is illegal, just as we already said above. It doesn't make any sense. I'm not entirely sure what your intent is, so I can't really help you. You'll want to read a tutorial on writing classes, and how to call methods.

Comment: @JEs If you're intending `start` to be called when a `test` is created (that should start with a capital btw), you need to call `start` from within the `test` constructor.